# How UI element "textview" can be operated by background thread "t"

Tags: java, android, multithreading

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textview);

        Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                textView.setText("Hello");
            }
        });
        
        t.start();
    }
}
```

I was expecting wrong thread exception. And what is meaning of `"scheduleTraversals in mThread=[main,5,main] currentThread=[thread-2,5,main]", how it is different from "CalledFromWrongThreadException".`

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Sub thread cannot modify the ui. There is a way to do this:

```
                Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        runOnUiThread(() -> {
                            textView.setText("Hello");
                        });
                    }
                });

                t.start();
```